# A way to assign user input to a variable and then share that variable across components

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, components, mxml

I currently have this to get user input:

```
    <s:TextInput id="searchInput" x="86" y="120" text="" change="onChange(event)" />
```

I use it in this component, but I want to use it in another component as well (so I can use the same variable on different screens essentially).

Comment: You should have a View that knows about the other "screen" you want to use it on listen for that change event, then provide the value through dependency injection.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a object that serves as a model for your views, and bind the search inputs to a keyword field on your model(use double binding).